# Excel vba clearing a range of data that is changing regularly

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to make a simple vba function in excel that clears a range of data, that goes from column A to K and row 6 to the bottom of the data, by finding the last used row and setting that as the end of the range. This is the code I have that is not working:

```
Sub clearNameData()

Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name Search")

lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

destSheet.range("A6:K & lMaxRows").ClearContents

End Sub
```

When I run this code it gives me the error "Run-time error '1004': MEthod 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

I cant figure out exactly how to get what im trying to do to work despite trying every syntax combination of my range definition. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by trying "A6:K" & lMaxRows. This will make your range argument A6:K500 (if 500 is the last row, for example). As it is currently constructed, you are feeding it the literal string of A6:KlmaxRows which is making it justifiably freak out a little bit.

Comment: You should add Option explicit at the top of your vba module. It will display you errors. I think the "" in the range aren't correctly placed also. (move the closing one just before the &)

Comment: @Joe thank you that worked perfectly. Can you write that as an answer?

Comment: @Vbasic4now Sure, I added it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I'm moving my comment to the answer.

The issue was with the line

```
destSheet.range("A6:K & lMaxRows").ClearContents
```

It needed to be changed to:

```
destSheet.range("A6:K" & lMaxRows).ClearContents
```

Note that the ending quotation mark moved. Supposing that lMaxRows is 500, this makes the range argument "A6:K500", which VBA can then evaluate as a range object. Before, it was the literal string A6:KlMaxRows, which VBA is *not* able to evaluate to a range object, since the variable is part of a string.

Comment: The range argument was `"A6:K & lMaxRows"`, without any modification (since the `&` was inside the double quotes it was not evaluated.).